# Project exe build doesn't work

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, build, exe

I have a problem in my visual studio or my computer that I can't figure out how to solve.

**This is the situation:**

I wrote a program and when I tried to run it from the .exe file, it didn't work. From debug, the program worked properly but if I tried to open a second instance of it, it didn't work.

In both cases, when I opened the second instance, or open the .exe file, the process of the program opened and didn't work (kept loading, or in the second debug instance case it got the VS stuck). When I tried to close the process I couldn't, even after closing visual studio task. The only way was to restart my PC, witch I did a lot.

After that, I tried to run the program on another computer and I found out it worked well.

I came back to my PC to try to solve the problem. I uninstalled VS13 and installed instead the VS15.
I opened a new WPF project. First thing i did was build it and open the .exe and it still didn't open!

---

This is my case guys. I would love to hear information on this problem, why it happend and how to solve it.
My PC is running Win 8.1 pro x64 operating system.

I found this that resembles my case:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/fbae61b4-47f1-4074-9261-505ebbd8d459/cant-run-visual-studio-2012-generated-exe-files?forum=vcgeneral

Thanks!

Comment: Try disabling any anti-virus software you have running temporarily and try again. (Unless you already have done)

Comment: Do you build on release for the program to run outside of VS?

Comment: I didn't tried to disable my anti-virus, it's a good idea, i will right now. I tried to build on release and debug and was trying to change the CPU configurations.

Answer (score 0):

The soultion to my problem was simple, i can't believe i didn't thought of it before. thanks to the first comment.

**Disabling avast anti-virus solve the problem**, the exe of my new and my original program is working fine.

Now all i need to do is find a way to make it work with the anti-virus working.